# How to pass google place api image to WordPress post thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, google-api-php-client

I am working on a project where i need to get google place data and create post of WordPress. For accomplishment of this i need google image to convert as post thumbnail.

Can anybody help me in that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use curl and fetch the thumbnail and display it

Comment: No, I cannot call image every time from google whenever i required to display post. I want it permanent as attachment inside wp